# Toad for oracle -- ORA-12514:TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, toad

I'm getting this error when connecting with Toad for Oracle.

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
Items Checked
TNS_ADMIN environment variable is defined as "D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin"
D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora was located
The following connect descriptor was found for OCP36T in the tnsnames.ora file
     ocp36t =
        (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = lx-cpora-t01k.lmig.com)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVER = DEDICATED)
          (SERVICE_NAME = ocp36t) 
        )
        )
      D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin\sqlnet.ora was located
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH specifies TNSNAMES in the sqlnet.ora file
Steps to Take
If the database was just started wait a few moments and try again as the database may be initializing
Verify that the connect descriptor for OCP36T has the correct SERVICE_NAME or SID component in the tnsnames.ora file
Verify that the listener is properly configured and that the database is registered with the listener
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is fairly confusing as to what you are attempting to do or what the issue is. I highly recommend reading through these as pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions and will help you get the best answers and more quickly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)

Comment: take a look at [SO: 7670290/tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670290/tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor)

Comment: @Newd pretty clear to me what he's trying to do. I agree with the dupe callouts though.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle is trying to tell you that this part is wrong:

```
(SERVICE_NAME = ocp36t)
```